# Is $\sin\left[{\pi \cdot \frac {1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}}\right]$ decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show that
$$\sin\left({\pi \cdot \frac {1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}}\right)$$ is decreasing for $n>1$? I think I have to show that the expression from inside the $\sin$ expression is between $\pi \over2$ and $\pi$ , but I do not know how. Can you please help me ? Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I would rather try between 0 and pi/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first show that $\frac{1}{n + \sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$ is decreasing from $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2  +1}$ to $0$ as $n$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$

now $\frac{\pi}{n + \sqrt{n^2+1}}$ decreases from $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2 + 1}< \pi/2$ to $0$

the $\sin$ is monotonic in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ gives you the required result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the sequence

$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$$

is decreasing and we have

$$0 < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

for all $n$.